# Why is steam assumed to be an ideal gas here?

Tags: thermodynamics

A swimmer coming out from a pool is covered with a film of water weighing about 18g. How much heat must be supplied to evaporate this water at 298 K? Calculate the internal energy of vaporisation at 100
o
C.
Δ
vap

H
⊝
for water at 373K =40.66 kJ mol
[image]

Comment: Because you need to assume it's an ideal gas to convert $p \Delta V$ to $\Delta n R T$  (recall that, for an ideal gas, $pV=nRT$).  The other assumption being made is that $\Delta V$ due to the loss of the liquid water is negligible.

Comment: Liquid water to gas has very negligible volume change ? @theorist

Comment: No.  You have two effects:  (1) you are decreasing the moles of liquid water; (2) you are increasing the moles of gaseous water by an equal amount.  Effect #1 causes a decrease in volume.  Effect #2 causes an increase in volume.  In doing the above calculation, you are ignoring effect #1, and only considering the change in volume due to effect #2.  I.e., you are not subtracting, from $\Delta V$, the change in the  volume of liquid water, because it is negligible compared to the gain in volume of gaseous water.  Specifically, $| \Delta V_{liquid}| \approx 1/1000 | \Delta V_{gas}|$

Comment: Using photos/screenshots of ( often even hand written ) text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged and can lead to ignoring a question by potential helpers or even its closure. The image text content cannot be indexed/searched for nor reused in the answers ( and scripts are challenges to interpret ). That puts unnecessary extra effort on others. Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of the essential parts. 
Use [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) for eventual formatting of formulas or expressions.

Comment: @Poutnik I have typed the question which is what needs to be searched.You can’t search the question by searching for solution.I get your point of not putting texts but if sometimes it is a big thing to type , photos can be easier.You have option for putting images as well.Images can be reused as well.Like you have written to rewrite essential parts - I wrote the question in which I had doubt and typed the doubt too.If it too big or maybe too complex sometimes to type it , then it also takes a lot of time of the person who is typing the doubt.

Comment: You have an option for putting photos.

Comment: I have also been typing my question using mathjax in mathematics stack exchange.But sometimes if it too big , I wrote the essential parts and put others as photo.

Comment: @Poutnik I would also be happy to know then how can I save my time and improve the quality of my question

Comment: Consider saving time of others in the first place. What if one wants to quote a part of your question ? Consider also the Q/A should have a permanent value for more users, not a one time value for just you. BTW it is not a long text, there are much longer ones here.

Comment: How can I easily and saving less time , convert it to mathjax.

Comment: Good is the Markdown Shortcuts for StackExchange script running within TamperMonky or similar addon in Firefox and I guess chrome too. Seach the chemistry.meta Se site for it. E.g.selection of H2SO4 and pressing CTRL+ALT+E put there \$\ce{H2SO4}\$, what looks like $\ce{H2SO4}$. See also https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE

Comment: I have a tablet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116646/discussion-between-poutnik-and-user277768).

Comment: At the equilibrium vapor pressure of water at 298 K, the PVT behavior of water vapor is very close to that of an ideal gas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical temperature of water is 647 K, its critical pressure is 22100 kPa, and its equilibrium vapor pressure at 298 K is 3.169 kPa.  So the reduced temperature is 0.461 and its reduced pressure is 0.000143.  From generalized compressibility factor charts, at this reduced temperature and pressure, the compressibility factor z is virtually indistinguishable from a value of 1, characteristic of an ideal gas.   Also, from the steam tables, the specific volume of water vapor under these conditions is 43.36 m^3/kg = 0.7805 m^3/mole.  So, $$\frac{Pv}{RT}=\frac{(3160)(0.7805)}{(8.314)(298.15)}=0.995$$